# Cannot boot to Windows after installing Elementary OS

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, mbr, elementaryos

Last week, I installed Elementary OS on one of my 3 partition so that I can dual boot it with Windows 8. After a couple days playing with eOS, I went back to Windows 8. The problem is that Windows 8 appeared in grub, but whenever I selected Windows 8 and hit Enter, it reloaded the grub.

I thought it was a problem with grub, so I decided to recover MBR from grub. Following some instructions I found online, I installed boot-repair in eOS and selected `recover mbr`, but it didn't fix the problem.

Then I thought it was the OS problem, and I decided to uninstall eOS. One important thing is that I cannot boot Windows 8. Then I tried booting from my USB stick that included Windows installation disk. I selected repair my computer, command prompt, and I selected the eOS partition and used `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` hoping it would fix the problem. But after reboot, the display just showed a black screen with a blinking cursor. I tried to reinstall Windows 8 on 2 of my 3 partitions (the other partition is important so I cannot install win 8 on it) but the black screen with blinking cursor showed up again!

How can I fix this so I can boot Windows 8 again?

Update: Thank you all you guy, i've fixed the problem, the reason i cannot boot to windows 8 is that the PBR removed, i dont know why but now i can boot to windows 8.

Comment: What did you read exactly?

Comment: #ramhound what do you mean? :/

Comment: I wanted to know what instructions you followed exactly.

Answer (score -1):

if you're okay with reformatting everything.  install dan's boot and nuke onto the usb stick and reformat the drive entirely then reinstall Windows 8.  I dont know for eOS but if it is supported in UEFI.  when you're in windows.  you need to use disk management to reduce the size of your main windows partition.  when installing eOS,  you'll see the option to install alongside Windows.  this works practically everytime.  If you need more info, just ask for it.  this is the place for!

Comment: Does dan's boot wipe all my partition?

Comment: dan's stands for Darik's Boot And Nuke (and is actually called DBAN) my bad.  and yes, as the name implies, it nukes the whole hard drive and completely erases everything on it.  it is a useful security tool but can be disastreous if used uncautiously...  kinda like a glowing hot iron bar.

Answer (score -1):

Install Elementary Os First ,then install Windows.

Because The Boot record will be Replaced when you install Linux with windows

practically system cant find windows,So you need to repair your MBR.

for more reference [Restore the Windows bootloader to MBR after dual-booting with Linux](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/)